# OIDCUser never authentication after authentication is done from IDP (Okta)

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect, okta, spring-oauth2

I had a weird issue with my Spring MVC application. Here I am using spring security 5.6.2 and spring 5.3.18 version. I configured my application to authenticate with Okta. After hitting secure resource it will redirect me to okta login page and after entering oauth user credentials okta redirect back to my application but authentication object was always null.

Inside doFilter method of **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter**.java, **requiresAuthentication**(..) was always evaluated as **false**.

```
private void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
}
```

It took me lot of time to find the root cause and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I debugged the code in OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter and **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter**, I found that when IDP redirects back to application using redirect-uri, It had /context-path/login/oauth2/code/okta as redirect endpoint but default value of filter processing url is as below.
**DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URI** = "/login/oauth2/code/*";

This will evaluate requiresAuthentication() always as false because of regex mismatch.

To fix we need to add  .redirectionEndpoint().baseUri("/context-path/login/oauth2/code/okta") into our security-configuration filter bean.